# Poor List Item Submit Logic in Sandbox Solution

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, sandbox

I have a web part for managing comments related to ongoing promotions. The web part is hosted in a Sandbox Solution because server access of all kinds is restricted (//sharepoint)

I have two main issues with my code.

1: Items submitted do not appear after postback, leaving user to think their comments was not saved,

2: PostBack data refires after page refresh, meaning if a user refreshes hoping to see their comments, it is re-submitted and saved.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
public string OfferID { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OfferID = Context.Request.QueryString["ItemID"];
            LoadOffers();
        }

protected void LoadOffers()
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(OfferID))
            {
                PopulateOfferDetails(OfferID);
                PopulateComments(OfferID);
                PopulateBestPractices(OfferID);
            }
            else
            {
                OfferID = "123";
                PopulateOfferDetails(OfferID);
                PopulateComments(OfferID);
                PopulateBestPractices(OfferID);
            }
        }

protected void PopulateComments(string offerID)
    {
        rcOiD.InnerText += " " + offerID;

        List<Comment> Comments = new List<Comment>();
        SPList TargetList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Offer Comments");
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.RowLimit = 100;
        query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"OfferID\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + offerID + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
        try
        {
            SPListItemCollection items = TargetList.GetItems(query);
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                commentsCount.InnerText = items.Count.ToString();
                SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
                string alias = user.Email.Substring(0, user.Email.IndexOf('@'));
                string profilePicBase = "<div class=\"profilePic\" " + "style=\"background-image:url('http://who/Photos/XX.jpg');\"" + ">&nbsp;</div>";
                foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                {
                    Comment c = new Comment();
                    c.Author = ((string)item["Created By"]).CleanUserName();
                    c.Body = (string)item["Body"];
                    c.Date = String.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy}", (DateTime)item["Created"]);
                    c.ProfilePic = profilePicBase.Replace("XX", alias);

                    Comments.Add(c);
                }
                Comments.Reverse();
                CommentRepeater.DataSource = Comments;
                CommentRepeater.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                commentsCount.InnerText = "0";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

protected void SubmitListItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
                string alias = user.Email.Substring(0, user.Email.IndexOf('@'));
                if (ListChoice.SelectedItem.Text == "comment")
                {
                    SPList TargetList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Offer Comments");
                    SPListItem item = TargetList.Items.Add();
                    item["Title"] = TitleBox.Text;
                    item["Body"] = BodyBox.Text;
                    item["OfferID"] = OfferID;
                    item["Alias"] = alias;
                    item.SystemUpdate();
                    TargetList.Update();
                }
                else
                {
                    SPList TargetList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Offer Best Practices");
                    SPListItem item = TargetList.Items.Add();
                    item["Title"] = TitleBox.Text;
                    item["Body"] = BodyBox.Text;
                    item["OfferID"] = OfferID;
                    item.SystemUpdate();
                    TargetList.Update();
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: I can confirm this isn't a databind() issue. The item.count being pulled on postback is being rendered properly, but is still 1 item short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume SubmitListItem is an event handler of an control on the page.
If that is so then as in your previous question, Page_Load is is fired before any control's event handler.
Therefore on postback your repeater is getting bound before the item addition occurs so on that load you do not get to see the new item.
To prevent this rebind the repeater after item addition.

Comment: But the page reloads for the post back. Page_Load fires again after SubmitListItem.

Comment: Please attach a debugger on the methods and it will be clear to you.

Comment: Here is the sequence of method/event firing : On first load - Init -Page_Load - PreRender - Render that's the end. When the user clicks on a control which triggers post back then the sequence is   - Init -Page_Load -Event handler of the control which triggered postback - PreRender - Render. So Page_Load( or CreateChildControls in case of webpart) is fired before eventhandler on postback. You see http being a stateless protocol even during postback, the page controls have to be recreated in page load before event handler method can be called.

Comment: For more info here is the msdn link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this only if not is page postback:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
        OfferID = Context.Request.QueryString["ItemID"];
        LoadOffers();
       }
    }
```

Comment: That solves the multiple submission problem, but doesn't help with the list item displaying. Thanks though, if no one else chimes in I'll mark it.

Comment: Ohh sorry, my bad, hoho never think of that, so, If You try a "location.reload" passing the comment id as an anchor as url parameter, so your customer can get it's comment displayed? A method to know if you should do a !Page.Postback would be to check your query string. Lets find this out.